# Bokeh: save plot (as HTML) but don't show it

Tags: python, html, plot, save, bokeh

I am using [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org) to produce HTML code including figures with `show` method This method ends on opening default browser with HTML opened in it.

I want to save the HTML code, without showing it. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 33):

Solution is to replace calls to `show` by calls to `save`.

Comment: Also if you would like to save custom HTML, or plots embedded in your own templates: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html

Answer (score 18):

Use `output_file({file_name})` instead of `output_notebook()`. You can call either `save` or `show` method. Remember each time you call save or show method the file will be rewritten.

[bokeh.io documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/io.html)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save

p = figure(title="Basic Title", plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p.circle([1, 2], [3, 4])
output_file("output_file_name.html")
save(p)
```